# How to convert a string to an ushort array

Tags: c#-3.0

How to convert a string to an ushort array..

Thank you very much for your help.

Thanks,
Lokesh

Comment: What are you going to do with this array - do you need a trailing zero because you're going to pass it a zero-terminated string?

Answer (score 4):

```
string s = "test";
ushort[] result = s.ToCharArray().Select(c => (ushort)c).ToArray();
```

Not sure if it's the best way, but it should work.

**Edit:** I didn't know `string` implemented `IEnumerable`. So actually you just need:

```
ushort[] result = s.Select(c => (ushort)c).ToArray();
```

Thanks to Jeff for pointing that out.

Comment: +1, though not necessary to convert the string to an array.  It can be left out.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't require verifiable IL, the fastest way (that avoids copying the string data entirely) that only uses the standard library is to use the unsafe overload of `Encoding.GetBytes`:

```
fixed (char* src = str) {
   fixed (ushort* dst = arr) {
       Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(src, str.Length, (byte*)dst, arr.Length * 2);
   }
}
```