# Casting and Linq Cast<T>()

Tags: linq, extension-methods, linq-to-objects, casting

When trying to answer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3361753/how-to-convert-a-string-to-an-ushort-array/3361841#3361841), I discovered the following:

```
string s = "test";

var result1 = s.Select(c => (ushort)c); // works fine

var result2 = s.Cast<ushort>(); // throws an invalid cast exception
```

Why does `Cast<T>()` fail here? Whats the difference?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Think you will find your answer here:

[Puzzling Enumerable.Cast InvalidCastException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/445471/puzzling-enumerable-cast-invalidcastexception)

The last part, under Edit:

> `Cast<T>()` is an extension method on
>   `IEnumerable` rather than
>   `IEnumerable<T>`. That means that by the
>   time each value gets to the point
>   where it's being cast, it has already
>   been boxed back into a `System.Object`

Comment: Thanks Martin. That's interesting. So Cast<T> should probably be avoided anyway for the inherent boxing performance penalty. I'm suprised MSDN doesn't mention that anywhere (that I could find, anyway).

Comment: `Cast<T>` is only intended to be used for bringing an `IEnumerable` up to the level of an `IEnumerable<T>`, where all the other LINQ operators are defined. Taking an `IEnumerable<TOriginal>` and converting it to an `IEnumerable<TOther>` is a projection, which is done by `Select`. The fact that `Cast` is even possible on an `IEnumerable<T>` is merely because `IEnumerable<T>` inherits from `IEnumerable` - no other reason.